# Databricks overnight run cell outputs not showing

Tags: python, pandas, azure-databricks

I am running a databricks notebook overnight due to the long compute time for hyperparam tuning. However, the results of the cells being run are not logged as normal once I turn off the PC. I've done this before and not had a problem and am at a loss as to why this is happening? Is there a setting or something that I have missed?

```
import pandas as pd
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer

pdf_train = pd.read_parquet(path_root + path_lab + path_train)

param_space = {
  
    "n_estimators": Integer(100, 1000),
    "max_features": Categorical(["auto", "sqrt", "log2", None]),
    "max_depth": Integer(10, 100),
    "min_samples_split": Integer(2, 10),
    "min_samples_leaf": Integer(2, 10)
  
}

gbt_cv = BayesSearchCV(estimator=GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=2710),
                       search_spaces=param_space,
                       n_iter=30,
                       cv=3,
                       scoring='average_precision',
                       n_jobs=-1
                       )

gbt_cv.fit(pdf_train[X],
           pdf_train[y],
          )
```

```
pd.DataFrame(gbt_cv.cv_results_).sort_values('rank_test_score')
```

```
gbt_cv.best_params_
```